# How to give caption to clocktables in org-mode when using step?

Tags: org-mode, org-clock, org-clock-table

When I create a clocktable without using `:step`, like the block given below, the table generated has a `#+CAPTION:`, that is exactly what I want.
Example:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :scope agenda-with-archives :block 2021-W31 :maxlevel 3 :hidefiles t :fileskip0 t :narrow 72! :match "-personal" :match "-nolog"
#+CAPTION: Clock summary at [2021-08-04 Wed 09:12], for week 2021-W31.
| Headline                                         |    Time |      |      |
|--------------------------------------------------+---------+------+------|
| *Total time*                                     |   *xxx* |      |      |
|--------------------------------------------------+---------+------+------|
| xxxx                                             |    xxxx |      |      |
| \_  xxxxxxxxxxxxxx                               |         | xxxx |      |
| \_    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                          |         |      | xxxx |
| \_    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                          |         |      | xxxx |
|--------------------------------------------------+---------+------+------|
| xxxxx                                            |    xxxx |      |      |
| \_  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |         | xxxx |      |
|--------------------------------------------------+---------+------+------|
| ...                                              |    .... |      |      |
| \_  LFA                                          |         | .... |      |
| \_    Tarefas                                    |         |      | .... |
#+END:
```

But when I give a `:step`, the many tables generated do not have captions, instead they have a simple line of text before the tables.
Example:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :scope agenda-with-archives :block 2021-W31 :maxlevel 4 :hidefiles t :fileskip0 t :narrow 75! :step day :match "-personal" :match "-nolog"

Daily report: [2021-08-02 Mon]
| Headline                                           |    Time |      |      |      |
|----------------------------------------------------+---------+------+------+------|
| *Total time*                                       | *xx:xx* |      |      |      |
|----------------------------------------------------+---------+------+------+------|
| 2021                                               |   xx:xx |      |      |      |
| \_  2021-08 August                                 |         |      | x:xx |      |
| \_    2021-08-02 Monday                            |         |      | x:xx |      |
| \_      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |         |      |      | x:xx |
| \_      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx     |         |      |      | x:xx |
|----------------------------------------------------+---------+------+------+------|
| ...                                                |    .... |      |      |      |

Daily report: [2021-08-03 Tue]
| Headline                                           |    Time |      |      |      |
|----------------------------------------------------+---------+------+------+------|
| *Total time*                                       | *xx:xx* |      |      |      |
|----------------------------------------------------+---------+------+------+------|
| 2021                                               |    x:xx |      |      |      |
| \_  2021-08 August                                 |         | x:xx |      |      |
| \_    2021-08-03 Tuesday                           |         |      | x:xx |      |
| \_      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx   |         |      |      | x:xx |
| \_      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx             |         |      |      | x:xx |
| \_      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |         |      |      | x:xx |
|----------------------------------------------------+---------+------+------+------|
| 2021i                                              |    x:xx |      |      |      |

Daily report: [2021-08-04 Wed]
| Headline                                           | Time   |      |      |      |
|----------------------------------------------------+--------+------+------+------|
| *Total time*                                       | *x:xx* |      |      |      |
|----------------------------------------------------+--------+------+------+------|
| 2021                                               | x:xx   |      |      |      |
| \_  2021-08 August                                 |        | x:xx |      |      |
| \_    2021-08-04 Wednesday                         |        |      | x:xx |      |
| \_      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |        |      |      | x:xx |

Daily report: [2021-08-05 Thu]
| Headline     | Time   |
|--------------+--------|
| *Total time* | *0:00* |

Daily report: [2021-08-06 Fri]
| Headline     | Time   |
|--------------+--------|
| *Total time* | *0:00* |

Daily report: [2021-08-07 Sat]
| Headline     | Time   |
|--------------+--------|
| *Total time* | *0:00* |

Daily report: [2021-08-08 Sun]
| Headline     | Time   |
|--------------+--------|
| *Total time* | *0:00* |
#+END:
```

Is there a way to may the clocktable generate `#+CAPTION:`s for the tables when I use `:step`?

Sorry if this is in the documentation, but I could not find it.

Thanks.

Comment: This is done by the function `org-clocktable-steps` in file `org-clock.el`, in the definition of the variable `step-header` - see the code [here](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/8df3e25db8a629bbffa883edadb13a55239ae4b7/lisp/org-clock.el#L2814).  The variable is used [here](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/8df3e25db8a629bbffa883edadb13a55239ae4b7/lisp/org-clock.el#L2853).There is no provision for making the strings into captions: you will have to override that function with your own, almost identical function that does `(insert "\n" "#+CAPTION: " step-header ...)` instead.

Comment: @NickD, I did as you instructed. Created a function called `my-clocktable-steps-with-captions` that is identical to `org-clocktable-steps` except for the `(insert "\n" "#+CAPTION: " step-header ...)` part, and in my Emacs configuration file I did `(setq org-clocktable-steps #'my-clocktable-steps-with-caption)`. The the result (the clocktables generated) remain the same. Do you have any idea of what am I missing?

Comment: Yes - `setq` will not work to set the function cell of a symbol: you need `fset` for that - do `C-h i g (elisp)Function cells` for details.. But for now, the easiest thing to do is to name your function `org-clocktable-steps`: it will completely override the original. If you don't like it, delete it from your init file (if that's how you got it into the system in the first place - if you just evaluated it in the `*scratch*` buffer or in an elisp buffer, you don't have to do anything special). Then restart emacs: that will install the standard function.

Comment: @NikD, thanks! Using `fset` solved the problem. The function is working as intended now.